# Docker with multiple projects aimed at dotnet core on linux

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I have a simple dotnet core console app which consists of 2 projects (c#)
The first is an external library that does some wrapping around a dotnet standard websockets client targeted at dotnet standard.

The other is the actual console app that takes the results from the websockets client and pushes it into a Service Bus queue in Azure.

It works fine using dotnet ConsoleApp.dll on my PC and inside a windows container. But when I run it in a Linux container it fails. I think its because it can't load the dependencies - even though they're in the output folder in the container.

My Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk
COPY WebsocketClient ./app/WebsocketClient
WORKDIR /
COPY ConsoleApp ./app/ConsoleApp
WORKDIR ./app/ConsoleApp
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
CMD ["dotnet", "./out/ConsoleApp.dll"]
```

root@e70c9468b11c:/app/ConsoleApp/out# dotnet run

Starting Websocket Client!
Socket state changed from None to Connecting

Unhandled Exception: Socket state changed from Connecting to Closed
Socket Closed reason: Empty
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to connect to the remote server) ---> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: Unable to connect to the remote server
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.d__16.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at PureWebSockets.PureWebSocket.Connect()
   at PureSocketCluster.PureSocketClusterSocket.Connect()
   at WebsocketClient.WsClient.Connect() in /app/WebsocketClient/WsClient.cs:line 187
   at ConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/ConsoleApp/Program.cs:line 62

root@e70c9468b11c:/app/ConsoleApp/out# ls

ConsoleApp.deps.json  ConsoleApp.runtimeconfig.json  Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.dll        PureSocketCluster.dll
ConsoleApp.dll        WebsocketClient.dll        Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.dll  PureWebSockets.dll
ConsoleApp.pdb        WebsocketClient.pdb        Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Comment: It looks like network configuration issue.  What is the host of the websocket source? Can you check do you have access from docker image to this host?

Comment: Yes I do have access. I can ping it etc no problem. I haven't specifically opened the websocket port but my understanding is that I don't need to. It also doesn't explain why it works in a windows container but not a linux container.